# PHP Switch Case not ending statement after "break;"

Tags: php, function, switch-statement, return

In following function if the input is blue then it is giving result as: "header content goes here Your favorite color is blue!" whereas it is supposed to give- "Your favorite color is blue!", please help me correcting it. If input is red then it is ending statement here as: "header content goes here" which is correct.

Please forgive me if I am asking silly question as I am new to PHP and I don't know if it is ok or not to use function as variable in switch case.

**test1.php**

```
<?php
function header2() { ?>
   header content goes here
<?php }

$good =header2();
$Input2 = $_POST['input'];

switch ($Input2) {
    case "red":
        echo $good;
        break;
    case "blue":
        echo "Your favorite color is blue!";
        break;
    case "green":
        echo "Your favorite color is green!";
        break;
    default:
        echo "Your favorite color is neither red, blue, nor green!";
}
?>
```

**main.js**

```
$('[id=stringone]').click(function(){
var string =$('[id=stringotherone]').val();
$.post('test1.php',{input: string}, function(data){
$('[id=stringotherthanone]').text(data);
});
});
```

**test.php**

```
 <! doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hwcb.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Go" id="stringone">
  <input type="text" id="stringotherone"/>
  <p><div id="stringotherthanone"></div></p>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/css.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `return` in the function otherwise it outputs when the function is called.

Example: https://3v4l.org/1Ptml vs. https://3v4l.org/ug778

`$good =header2();` is outputting the `header content goes here`, not the `echo $good;` in the `switch`. That actually does nothing because that variable is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<?php
function header2() { ?>
   header content goes here
<?php }
```

to

```
<?php
function header2() { 
   return 'header content goes here';
}
```

Comment: I think an explanation would be nice :)